# beta distribution as ratio gamma distributions

Tags: beta-function, gamma-distribution

I need a proof of this statement please:

Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be independent random variables, where $Y_1$ is gamma distributed with parameters $\alpha$ and 1 and $Y_2$ is gamma distributed with parameters $\beta$ and 1. Then the random variable $X$ presented by the following formula:
\begin{equation} \label{lemma5}
    \displaystyle X = \frac{Y_1}{Y_1+Y_2}
\end{equation}
is beta distributed with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: please show your work and you will be helped where you are stuck

Comment: Hi tommik, It's a bit embarassing but I really don't know how to start. I read this in an article and tried to find a proof of it but didn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not difficult. I cannot show you the entire proof because you question is without your own work but this is a useful hint:

To simplify the notation, let me set $X,Y$ as the two independent Gamma rv and let's derive the law of

$$U=\frac{X}{X+Y}$$

The starting point is the following system

$$\begin{cases}
u=\frac{x}{x+y} \\
v=x
\end{cases}\rightarrow \begin{cases}
x=v \\
y=v\frac{1-u}{u}
\end{cases}$$

with Jacobian $|J|=\frac{v}{u^2}$

Substitute in $f_{XY}(x,y)$ and solve the integral in $dv$ finding your beta density. It is not difficult so show your works amending your question and, just in case, I will take you to the solution